# Como eu posso filtrar objetos em um Array com Typescript?

Tags: array, typescript, filter

Exemplo:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) { 
   return (element >= 10); 
} 

var passed = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough); 
console.log("Test Value : " + passed );
```

Comment: Exatamente da mesma forma que você fez.

Comment: Eu peguei esse exemplo em um apostila. Consegui entender pela resposta do NoobSaibot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) veio para facilitar a vida, se ela não fosse criada, você teria que percorrer o objeto utilizando [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) / [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) e ou [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), fazendo a condição e adicionando o elemento que passou no teste em um novo objeto, veja os exemplos:

```js
let objetos = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44];
let resultadoA = [],
    resultadoB = [],
    resultadoC = [];

for (let i = 0; i < objetos.length; i++) {
  if (objetos[i] >= 10) {
    resultadoA.push(objetos[i]);
  }
}

for (let objB of objetos) {
  if (objB >= 10) {
    resultadoB.push(objB);
  }
}

objetos.forEach(objC => {
  if (objC >= 10) {
    resultadoC.push(objC);
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultadoA), JSON.stringify(resultadoB), JSON.stringify(resultadoC));
```

Já utilizando a função [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), ela irá percorrer o array e chamar a função que foi informada, passando como parâmetro: *o elemento atual, o índice atual e o array*. Se você imprimir esses parâmetros no console, terá o seguinte resultado:

```
12  // Primeiro elemento do array
0   // Índice 0
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44]
5   // Segundo elemento do array
1   // Índice 1
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44]
8   // Terceiro elemento do array
2   // Índice 2
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44]
130 // Quarto elemento do array
3   // Índice 3
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44]
44  // Quinto elemento do array
4   // Índice 4
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44]
```

Note que ela percorreu o array elemento por elemento, e retornou um novo array com os elementos que passaram no teste:

```
"Test Value : 12,130,44"
```

Além do exemplo informado na pergunta, você também pode fazer assim:

```js
var resultadoA = ['PHP', 'C#', 'Java', 'JavaScript'].filter(el => el === 'JavaScript');

// Retornada array vazio, porque nenhum elemento
// passou no teste.
var resultadoB = ['PHP', 'C#', 'Java', 'JavaScript'].filter(el => el === 'Python');

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultadoA),JSON.stringify(resultadoB));
```